# Add a new Editable Row to Grid View without using Footer template or footer property of grid view

Tags: asp.net

we have a grid view to which we are binding data dynamically using database connection through web.config file. now we want to add a new editable row to grid view upon button click and whatever data we enter that should be updated in grid view.

is that possible?

if yes, please provide solution.
if no, why ?

Comment: What have you done ? Share your code.

Comment: Why without using the footer? You want to mix data-rows with non-datarows which will make your code less readable and more error-prone. Why? (you would have to create a pseudo-datasource for the grid with one row)

Comment: Because,footer display the last row of gridview.But,i need top of the gridview.

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684059/adding-a-new-row-in-gridview) question answered already, inserting new row at the Top.